# How to use Shared Preference to save the data from edit text and display it on ListView in another Activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, android-adapter

I have created two activities `MainActivity` and `EditorActivity`. I want to take two strings from Editor Activity and display those strings in `MainActivity's` ListView, whenever the back button from `EditorActivity` is clicked.
My code shows only one item and every time a new List is getting created.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.writedown;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton addNoteFab;
    private ArrayList<NoteItem> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    NoteAdapter adapter;
    private static final String SHARED_PREF = "pref";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addNoteFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_note);
        adapter = new NoteAdapter(this, notes);
        addNoteFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String title = sharedPreferences.getString("title",  null);
        String desc = sharedPreferences.getString("note", null);
        notes.add(new NoteItem(title, desc));
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EditorActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.writedown;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText edit_title;
    private EditText edit_note;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static final String SHARED_PREF = "pref";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);
        edit_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_title);
        edit_note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_note);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("title", edit_title.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("note", edit_note.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(EditorActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**activity_editor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".EditorActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/editor_title"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/editor_note"
        android:gravity="start"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom Data type - NoteItem.java**

```
package com.example.android.writedown;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoteItem {
    private String title, note;
    private TextView titleView, descView;
    public NoteItem(String mTitle, String mNote) {
        title = mTitle;
        note = mNote;
    }

    public String getNote() { return note; }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }
}
```

**Custom Adapter - NoteAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.android.writedown;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.List;

public class NoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> {
    public NoteAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<NoteItem> notes) {
        super(context, 0, notes);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        NoteItem currNote = getItem(position);
        String title = currNote.getTitle();
        String desc = currNote.getNote();
        TextView note_title = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        TextView note_desc = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.note_description);

        if(title!=null) {
            note_title.setText(title);
            note_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if(desc!=null) {
            note_desc.setText(desc);
            note_desc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

**note_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Removed `android-recyclerview` from the tags as this is about the ListView

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `SharedPreference` with your key and every time replacing the same key values `title` and `note` which, as expected, would keep on overwriting the existing values instead of creating a list as per your requirement.

If you just need to save the data in one Activity and show it in a different activity, you can simply save the data as a list in the local storage (or even a remote database, if you prefer) and then get that instance to keep adding new elements to the list.

You can use [PaperDB](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper) which is an easy-to-use NoSQL-based library for saving data in local storage. Check the link for integration, and once integrated you can simply save a file simply as:

```
Paper.book().write("editor_list", <you_list_here>);
```

Create the list like:

```
ArrayList<NoteItem> noteList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then get the list instance from the local file in the `EditorActivity` as:

```
ArrayList<NoteItem> noteList = Paper.book().read("editor_list", new ArrayList<>()); // this will give you empty list if there are no existing items.
```

Then just add your `title` and `note` as a separate object of model class `NoteItem` and add it to the list like:

```
noteList.add(<your_object_here>)
```

Then you can use the `write` function again to pass this updated list and save the changes in the local file. For showing the list in the `ListView` simply get the file again as a list and pass the list to the adapter.

This should get it done what you're expecting!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your MainActivity everything is written in onCreate method. If you understand the lifecycle of activity, onCreate calls only one time per launch of activity, I suggest to for another method like this
[How to manage startActivityForResult on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)
and you don't require anything extra, just need to change the Intent calling with **startActivityForResult** and get in MainActivity in **onActivityResult**

Comment: Using these methods stores and displays the data but data is getting removed after the app's cache is cleared.

Comment: Of course it will be cleared. That's how the system works. If you want to keep the data, may be switch to cloud storage and API web service.